# SQL Server INSERT INTO using transaction

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have a stored procedure that does the following:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl1
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 
    FROM Tbl2
```

My question is: does this need a transaction with commit? From looking online it does not seem so. I will have it as part of a nightly batch process so want to make sure it behaves properly. Should I do a try catch in this case?

Comment: In SQL Server, if you *do not* explicitly specify a transaction, then each statement is executed *in an **implicit** transaction* of its own. So this `INSERT` - even when not part of an explicit transaction - will always either fully work, or fully fail - you won't get half the rows inserted and then it aborts - it's an automatic "all-or-nothing" approach

Answer (score 2):

If you have just only this statement it doesn't matter, because implicitly it is a `transaction`. In case of failure it won't insert any rows, but in other case it will commit the changes. You might have a scenario when at the beggining of your procedure you delete rows and then inserting rows into a table. In such scenario it might be good to wrap it up in one transaction. Thanks to this when `delete` succeedes, but `insert` fails you will still have data in your table.